# LINQ: Query a collection within a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

I have following structure:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int ProductID { get set; }
}
```

I need to get the collection of customers that ordered ProductID = 6. What would the fluent style LINQ look like?

I tried below with no luck:

```
var customers = allCustomers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders.Select(o => o.ProductID.Equals(6))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var customers = allCustomers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductID == 6));`

Comment: In VB:  `Dim customers = allCustomers.Where(Function(c) c.Orders.Any(Function(o) o.ProductID = 6))`

Answer (score 3):

```
allCustomers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductID == 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var customers = allCustomers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductID == 6));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want:

```
var query = allCustomers.Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductID == 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way would be to try from the other side like this

```
var customers from p in Order where p.ProductId == 6 select p.Customer
```

And of course you need the add the Customer property in the Order class like this

```
public class Order
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int ProductID { get set; }
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```